# Ввод двумерного int массива с клавиатуры на java

Tags: java, массивы, ввод, поток-ввода

Мне нужно просто с клавиатуры ввести строки типа `1 2 3 Enter`, `4 5 6 Enter` и получить int-овый массив `{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}`.

Как это сделать? Через `Scanner` или др.?

Comment: Да, можно через сканер.

Comment: Я знаю. Но очень хотелось бы код. Пожалуйста

Comment: ты можешь считать строку, разделить ее по пробелам с помощью функции `split(" ")`, и преобразовать каждый элемент в число.

Comment: А что у вас не получается?

Answer (score 1):

Можно стримами вот так:

```
static int[][] getMatrix(InputStream is, int x, int y) {
    var array = new int[y][];
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    IntStream.range(0, y).forEach(i -> {
        array[i] = new int[x];
        IntStream.range(0, x).forEach(j -> array[i][j] = scanner.nextInt());
    });

    return array;
}
```

а можно и по-старинке, так:

```
static int[][] getMatrixLegacy(InputStream is, int x, int y) {
    int[][] array = new int[y][];
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) {
        array[i] = new int[x];
        for (int j = 0; j < x; j++) {
            array[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();
        }
    }

    return array;
}
```

И затем вызываете и распечатываете вот так:

```
var array = getMatrix(System.in, 3, 2);
Arrays.stream(array).forEach(l -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(l)));
```

или так:

```
int[][] array = getMatrixLegacy(System.in, 3, 2);
for (int[] line : array) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(line));
}
```

Comment: стримы, на мой взгляд, слишком сложны для тех, кто не может считать матрицу. И во втором решении  не обеспечивается ввод матрицы с переводом после каждой строки. Точнее, можно вводить перевод строки сколько угодно раз, тогда как в задании -- один раз для каждой строки

Comment: Стримы всего лишь непривычны, поскольку появились в Java относительно недавно. В задании нет ограничения на количество нажатий Enter. Есть лишь способ ввода данных, который должен поддерживаться и который поддерживается в обоих решениях.

Comment: цитата: "нужно просто с клавиатуры ввести строки типа `1 2 3 Enter`, `4 5 6 Enter`"

Comment: И что, когда вы вводите нажимая `[1][пробел][2][пробел][3][Enter][4][пробел][5][пробел][6][Enter]` у вас что-то не работает?

Comment: будет работать. Согласен, извини

Answer (score 0):

```
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String text = in.nextLine();
    int m = 4;
    int n = (stext.length()/m);
        if (n == 0) n = 1;
    char[][] text = new char[n][m];
    int l=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            text[i][j] =stext.charAt(l);
            l++;
        }
    }
 ...
```

Comment: Мы не знаем заранее размеры строк и их кол-во.